# How do I get the list title to use inside xslt?

Tags: list, javascript, xslt, dialog

I'm using a script to create a button, so that the user can create new form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayLayover(url) {
        var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
        options.url = url;
        options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, null);
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }
    </script> 
    <a class="btn btn-orange" href='javascript:displayLayover(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/Lists/MyList/NewForm.aspx?IsDlg=1")'>Create your profile</a>
```

Now I would like to enter this script inside a xsl file so that it always creates a button to create a new item for this list.

But is it possible to enter the current list name, instead of changing the name all the time manually?